# Adding elements to List in Flutter from For statement?

Tags: list, dart, iteration, element, flutter

I'm receiving the following error while trying to add elements from my for loop to my `List`...

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAll' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: addAll("LrWr826cd3Y")
```

Here is my code...

```
Future getData() async {
    //Map videoId;

    String url = 'https://Youtube API';
    var httpClient = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.read(url);
    Map data = JSON.decode(response);
    var videos = data['items']; //returns a List of Maps

    List searchTitles;
    List searchIds;
    List searchImages;

    for (var items in videos) {
      //iterate over the list
      Map myMap = items; //store each map
      final video = (myMap['id'] as Map);
      print(video['videoId']);
      searchIds.addAll(video['videoId']);
      final details = (myMap['snippet'] as Map);
      final videoimage = (details['thumbnails'] as Map);
      final medium = (videoimage['medium'] as Map);

    }

    setState(() { });

    if (!mounted) return;
  }
```

`print(video['videoId']);` successfully lists the 3 Youtube video ids as Strings. `searchIds.addAll(video['videoId']);` throws the error.  I've tried both `searchIds.add` and `searchIds.addAll`.  Where am I going wrong?

I would like to eventually push these lists to my List class here..

```
class CardInfo {
  //Constructor
  List id;
  List title;
  List video;

  CardInfo.fromJson(List json) {
    this.id;
    this.title;
    this.video;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not instantiating your searchIds object. add this

```
List searchIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

(Or)

```
List searchIds = new List();
```

Comment: This is how I got it to work for Flutter...   `List searchIds = new List();`

Comment: I see your problem is fixed. Good job.

Comment: List searchIds = new List(); this is worked for me.

Comment: You can also use List searchIds = [];